# Does Steam support Shared Libraries?

Tags: steam

I know steam has nothing to do with whether the game has dynamic libraries or not, but a lot of games should be using the **same** dynamic libraries.

Does Steam currently have a way to **reuse 1 dynamic library across multiple games**, without creating copies of said library of course? I've taken a look into my own Steam library by taking 2 Source games and wild picking a few dynamic libraries and checking if the other one has them. I didn't really find a lot of matches, but I did find matches and I did find similar libraries. (`valve_bink.dll` and `binkw32` for example)

Comment: I think what you are asking is a recipe for chaos.. Shipping self-contained packages is the way to go, after all the shared libraries are not that heavy and this way you assure a package that is guaranteed to work. Otherwise you might easily find trouble with different library versions, different compile options than what you expect and so on..

Comment: @Grimshaw That was what I was thinking too, but at the end you would just have to change your program to match the Steam shared library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not something you should really *want* to do. Consider what Steam [has to do with DirectX](http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2011/08/03/why-steam-makes-you-install-directx-repeatedly/). Getting into the mess of shared dynamic libraries isn't likely to be worth the trouble.

I haven't seen any scenarios where Steam games will share DLLs between each other. As Grimshaw said in his comment, it adds a lot of complexity for nothing other than saving a little disk space.